# Как сверстать кнопку?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

[image: Добрый день. Как можно так заверстать?]

Как можно такую кнопку сверстать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не уверен что похоже ... просто как вариант решения

**это если без svg**

```css
.item {
  width: 240px;
  height: 66px;
  margin: 60px;
  perspective: 200px;
}

.item-outer {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border: 6px double pink;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px pink inset;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.item-outer p {
  margin-left: -20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px pink;
  color: pink;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-outer">
    <p>В корзину</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тоже неплохой вариант. Я вообще немного неправильно составил вопрос, как именно таких срезов добиться? бордери бла-бла я то сделал. А вот как с обрезкой хз. Думал с помощью  clip-path но немного не то получается.

Comment: @Taras о каких срезах речь ?

Comment: Я про нестандартную форму. Более узкая справа и боле широкая в левою крае.

Comment: @Taras это на svg делается, я просто показал на css - хотите научу ...там что угодно можно нарисовать

Comment: Если можете показать/дать совет/научить буду крайне благодарен)

Comment: @Taras  есть тем вивер ?

Comment: Увы нет, и дома буду только завтра. Можете дать совет что-то почитать/видео урок по svg?

Comment: @Taras скачайте inkscape или любой удобный редактор svg и попробуйте там ..это пока всё ...

Comment: Понял. Большое спасибо)

Comment: Очень даже похоже, мб еще skew добавить

Comment: @StrangerintheQ салам Костян ..как справил ?

Comment: @MaximLensky да как то и не отмечали особо в этом году.. 1 ого числа гости были и все

Comment: @StrangerintheQ рад был видеть тебя ... всего налучшего

Comment: @MaximLensky И тебе благ всяческих

Answer (score 9):

### Решение SVG

Если нужно сверстать точь в точь до пикселя, то конечно без SVG и векторного редактора не обойтись.

- Загружаете вашу картинку с её размерами `358 х 115px` в векторный
  редактор:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="358" height="115" viewBox="0 0 358 115" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/F95y6.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

1. Инструментом `Рисовать кривые Безье` <kbd>shift+F6</kbd>, **см. цифра 1**  на рисунке, и наносите по контуру загруженной картинки узловые точки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. С помощью инструмента - `Редактировать узлы контура` на рис. (2) выделяете эти узлы - они должны окраситься в жёлтый цвет
3. Делаете их `автоматически сглаженными` (3) и рычагами управления узлов, добиваетесь нужной формы кривой.
4. Сохраняете файл в формате `*.svg` и копируете из него формулы `path` в другой файл SVG.

Смотрите результат, если форма кривой не устраивает, снова возвращаетесь в векторный редактор и корректируете.

Добавляем текст в SVG:

```
<text class="txt" x="179" y="65"  > В КОРЗИНУ </text>
```

Добавляем фильтр к тексту:

```
<defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow" width="120%" height="120%">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic"  stdDeviation="1" result="shadow" />
       
      <feOffset in="shadow" dx="2" dy="1" result="shadow" />
           
      <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="1.6 1.7 1.8 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 -0.04" result="shadow" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"  />
    </filter>
  </defs>
```

Ниже полный код:

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%
}

#border1, #border2 {
fill:none;
stroke:#C532D4;
stroke-width:2;

}

.txt {
fill:#C532D4;
text-anchor:middle;
font-size:32px;
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 358 115" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >   
<defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow" width="120%" height="120%">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic"  stdDeviation="1" result="shadow" />
       
      <feOffset in="shadow" dx="2" dy="1" result="shadow" />
           
      <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="1.6 1.7 1.8 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 -0.04" result="shadow" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"  />
    </filter>
  </defs>   

 <path id="border1" d="m23.1 87.7c0.9-6.6 2.3-9.4 3.6-15.3 2.9-12.6 6-24.2 9.5-39.7 1-4.3 1.7-7.3 2.8-11.6 1.1-4.6 4.2-9 11.1-8.2 18.4 2.2 16.7 1.4 25.3 2 38.8 2.7 71.9 5.8 109.3 7.8 26.3 1.4 53.4 2.8 83 4.3 21.6 1.1 50.6 3 69.5 3.7 3.7 0.1 4.8-1.2 4.8 7.7-0.1 7.5 0 12.5 0.2 20.1 0.1 2.2 0.1 4.8 0.3 8 0.5 10.9-3 10.9-5.5 11.1-9.8 0.8-19.2 1.5-28.3 2.2-84.5 6.2-147 9.1-277 16.4-3.3 0.2-9.3-2.2-8.4-8.4z" />
  <path id="border2" d="m18.3 89.7c2.6-12.9 5.2-22.4 7.9-33.6 2.5-10.6 4.2-20.5 7.4-31.9 1.8-6.3 5.7-15 12.2-15.3 14.1-0.7 27.9 1.5 41.9 2.2 14.3 0.7 28.5 1.3 42.8 2.2 13.5 0.9 27.1 2.2 40.6 3.1 14.7 0.9 29.4 1.4 44.1 2.2 14.4 0.8 28.8 1.7 43.2 2.6 12.1 0.8 24.1 1.9 36.2 2.6 11.3 0.7 22.7 1 34.1 1.6 2.7 0.2 5.4 0.4 8.1 0.5 4 0.2 8.7 2.7 8.6 6.5 0 1.3 0 2.6 0 3.8-0.1 12.4-0.2 22.3-0.1 35.6 0 2.6-0.4 9.7-4.5 10.3-8.2 1.1-17.9 1.2-26.9 1.7-30.4 1.9-60.8 3.8-91.2 5.7-28.2 1.8-56.5 3.6-84.7 5.2-21 1.2-41.9 2.2-62.9 3.5-13.4 0.8-26.8 1.6-40.2 2.6-8.4 0.6-17.9-4.8-16.6-11.4z" />
<text class="txt" x="179" y="65"  > В КОРЗИНУ </text> 
</svg>   
</div>
```

Comment: зачем атрибут in ?

Comment: @Leks Теорию фильтров можно почитать для ознакомления https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/

Answer (score 5):

### Анимация рамок

В вопросе не было такой задачи, пост в качестве бонуса

Добавляем дополнительные серые рамки, которые будут служить для показа трассы анимации розовых рамок Просто копируем `path` розовых рамок и окрашиваем в серый цвет.

Анимация будет реализована с помощью изменения атрибутов `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`

Полная длина внутренней рамки - `740px`

Длина внешней рамки - `773px`

**Одновременная анимация двух рамок SVG**

`stroke-dashoffset` уменьшается от максимума до нуля, реализуя тем самым рисование бордюров вокруг кнопки

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#111;
}
#trace_In {
fill:none;
stroke:#828282;
}
#trace_Out {
fill:none;
stroke:#656565;
}

#border_In {
fill:none;
stroke:gold;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-dasharray:740px;
stroke-dashoffset:740px;
}
#border_Out {
fill:none;
stroke:gold;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-dasharray:773px;
stroke-dashoffset:773px;

}

.txt {
fill:gold;
text-anchor:middle;
font-size:40px;
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
fill-opacity:0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 358 115" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >   
<defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow" width="120%" height="120%">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic"  stdDeviation="1" result="shadow" />
       
      <feOffset in="shadow" dx="2" dy="1" result="shadow" />
           
      <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="1.6 1.7 1.8 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 -0.04" result="shadow" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"  />
    </filter>
  </defs> 
 
   <!-- Серая внутренняя рамка, трасса анимации -->
 <path id="trace_In" d="m23.8 87.7c0.9-6.6 2.3-9.4 3.6-15.3 2.9-12.6 6-24.2 9.5-39.7 1-4.3 1.6-6.4 2.6-10.7 1.1-4.6 4.1-8.5 11.1-8.2 18.7 0.6 24.6 1.1 24.6 1.1 0 0 71.9 5.8 109.3 7.8 26.3 1.4 47.7 2.3 77.3 3.8 21.6 1.1 49.9 2.6 68.2 3.4 6.6 0.3 10.6-0.7 10.5 8.2-0.1 14.6-0.2 34.6-0.2 34.6 0 0 0.8 5.5-6.3 5.7-9.8 0.3-16.6 0.7-25.7 1.4-84.5 6.2-146.2 9.1-276.2 16.4-3.3 0.2-9.3-2.2-8.4-8.4z" />
 
 <!-- Жёлтая внутренняя рамка -->
 <path id="border_In" d="m23.8 87.7c0.9-6.6 2.3-9.4 3.6-15.3 2.9-12.6 6-24.2 9.5-39.7 1-4.3 1.6-6.4 2.6-10.7 1.1-4.6 4.1-8.5 11.1-8.2 18.7 0.6 24.6 1.1 24.6 1.1 0 0 71.9 5.8 109.3 7.8 26.3 1.4 47.7 2.3 77.3 3.8 21.6 1.1 49.9 2.6 68.2 3.4 6.6 0.3 10.6-0.7 10.5 8.2-0.1 14.6-0.2 34.6-0.2 34.6 0 0 0.8 5.5-6.3 5.7-9.8 0.3-16.6 0.7-25.7 1.4-84.5 6.2-146.2 9.1-276.2 16.4-3.3 0.2-9.3-2.2-8.4-8.4z" >
     <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    dur="2s"
    values="740;0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path>  
 <!-- Серая внешняя рамка, трасса анимации -->
  <path id="trace_Out" d="m19.3 88.8c1.4-10 4.3-21.5 6.9-32.7 2.8-11.9 5.4-25.1 8.5-35.6 1.3-6.4 5.2-11.8 11.8-12 13.6-0.5 27.8 1.5 41.8 2.2 14.3 0.7 28.2 1.7 42.3 2.6 13.6 0.9 27.4 2.1 40.9 2.9 14.7 0.9 29.2 1.5 43.8 2.3 14.4 0.8 28.8 1.7 43.2 2.6 12.3 0.8 24.9 1.7 37 2.5 11.3 0.7 22.2 1.1 33.3 1.8 2.7 0.2 5.4 0.4 8.1 0.5 4 0.2 8.7 2.7 8.6 6.5 0 1.3 0 2.6 0 3.8-0.1 12.4-0.1 35.6-0.1 35.6 0 0 2 10-4.5 10.3-8.3 0.4-17.9 1.2-26.9 1.7-30.4 1.9-60.8 3.8-91.2 5.7-28.2 1.8-56.5 3.6-84.7 5.2-21 1.2-41.9 2.3-62.9 3.5C60.6 99.2 46.9 101 31.5 100.9 24.8 100.8 18.3 95.4 19.3 88.8Z" />
   <!-- Жёлтая внешняя рамка -->
  <path id="border_Out" d="m19.3 88.8c1.4-10 4.3-21.5 6.9-32.7 2.8-11.9 5.4-25.1 8.5-35.6 1.3-6.4 5.2-11.8 11.8-12 13.6-0.5 27.8 1.5 41.8 2.2 14.3 0.7 28.2 1.7 42.3 2.6 13.6 0.9 27.4 2.1 40.9 2.9 14.7 0.9 29.2 1.5 43.8 2.3 14.4 0.8 28.8 1.7 43.2 2.6 12.3 0.8 24.9 1.7 37 2.5 11.3 0.7 22.2 1.1 33.3 1.8 2.7 0.2 5.4 0.4 8.1 0.5 4 0.2 8.7 2.7 8.6 6.5 0 1.3 0 2.6 0 3.8-0.1 12.4-0.1 35.6-0.1 35.6 0 0 2 10-4.5 10.3-8.3 0.4-17.9 1.2-26.9 1.7-30.4 1.9-60.8 3.8-91.2 5.7-28.2 1.8-56.5 3.6-84.7 5.2-21 1.2-41.9 2.3-62.9 3.5C60.6 99.2 46.9 101 31.5 100.9 24.8 100.8 18.3 95.4 19.3 88.8Z" >
     <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    dur="2s"
    values="773;0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path> 
<text class="txt" x="179" y="65"  > В КОРЗИНУ
  <animate attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="2s" values="0.2;1" begin="svg1.mouseover"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
</text> 
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Анимация  рамки вокруг кнопки CSS**

Всё тоже самое только с помощью анимации CSS

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%
}
#trace_In {
fill:none;
stroke:#d3d3d3;
}
#trace_Out {
fill:none;
stroke:#d3d3d3;
}

#border_In {
fill:transparent;
stroke:#C532D4;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-dasharray:745px;
stroke-dashoffset:745px;

}
#border_In:hover {
animation: 2s dash_In  linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash_In {
to {stroke-dashoffset:0;
    stroke-width:9px;}
}

#border_Out {
fill:transparent;
stroke:#C532D4;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-dasharray:772px;
stroke-dashoffset:772px;


}
#border_Out:hover {
animation: 2s dash_Out  linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash_Out {
to {stroke-dashoffset:0;}
}

.txt {
fill:#C532D4;
text-anchor:middle;
font-size:40px;
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 358 115" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >   
<defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow" width="120%" height="120%">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic"  stdDeviation="1" result="shadow" />
       
      <feOffset in="shadow" dx="2" dy="1" result="shadow" />
           
      <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="1.6 1.7 1.8 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 -0.04" result="shadow" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"  />
    </filter>
  </defs> 
 
   <!-- Серая внутренняя рамка, трасса анимации -->
 <path id="trace_In" d="m23.1 87.7c0.9-6.6 2.3-9.4 3.6-15.3 2.9-12.6 6-24.2 9.5-39.7 1-4.3 1.7-7.3 2.8-11.6 1.1-4.6 4.2-9 11.1-8.2 18.4 2.2 16.7 1.4 25.3 2 38.8 2.7 71.9 5.8 109.3 7.8 26.3 1.4 53.4 2.8 83 4.3 21.6 1.1 50.6 3 69.5 3.7 3.7 0.1 4.8-1.2 4.8 7.7-0.1 7.5 0 12.5 0.2 20.1 0.1 2.2 0.1 4.8 0.3 8 0.5 10.9-3 10.9-5.5 11.1-9.8 0.8-19.2 1.5-28.3 2.2-84.5 6.2-147 9.1-277 16.4-3.3 0.2-9.3-2.2-8.4-8.4z" />
 
 <!-- Розовая внутренняя рамка -->
 <path id="border_In" d="m23.1 87.7c0.9-6.6 2.3-9.4 3.6-15.3 2.9-12.6 6-24.2 9.5-39.7 1-4.3 1.7-7.3 2.8-11.6 1.1-4.6 4.2-9 11.1-8.2 18.4 2.2 16.7 1.4 25.3 2 38.8 2.7 71.9 5.8 109.3 7.8 26.3 1.4 53.4 2.8 83 4.3 21.6 1.1 50.6 3 69.5 3.7 3.7 0.1 4.8-1.2 4.8 7.7-0.1 7.5 0 12.5 0.2 20.1 0.1 2.2 0.1 4.8 0.3 8 0.5 10.9-3 10.9-5.5 11.1-9.8 0.8-19.2 1.5-28.3 2.2-84.5 6.2-147 9.1-277 16.4-3.3 0.2-9.3-2.2-8.4-8.4z" >
   <!--  <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    dur="2s"
    values="745;0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> -->
 </path>  
 <!-- Серая внешняя рамка, трасса анимации -->
  <path id="trace_Out" d="m18.3 89.7c2.6-12.9 5.2-22.4 7.9-33.6 2.5-10.6 4.2-20.5 7.4-31.9 1.8-6.3 5.7-15 12.2-15.3 14.1-0.7 27.9 1.5 41.9 2.2 14.3 0.7 28.5 1.3 42.8 2.2 13.5 0.9 27.1 2.2 40.6 3.1 14.7 0.9 29.4 1.4 44.1 2.2 14.4 0.8 28.8 1.7 43.2 2.6 12.1 0.8 24.1 1.9 36.2 2.6 11.3 0.7 22.7 1 34.1 1.6 2.7 0.2 5.4 0.4 8.1 0.5 4 0.2 8.7 2.7 8.6 6.5 0 1.3 0 2.6 0 3.8-0.1 12.4-0.2 22.3-0.1 35.6 0 2.6-0.4 9.7-4.5 10.3-8.2 1.1-17.9 1.2-26.9 1.7-30.4 1.9-60.8 3.8-91.2 5.7-28.2 1.8-56.5 3.6-84.7 5.2-21 1.2-41.9 2.2-62.9 3.5-13.4 0.8-26.8 1.6-40.2 2.6-8.4 0.6-17.9-4.8-16.6-11.4z" />
   <!-- Розовая внешняя рамка -->
  <path id="border_Out" d="m18.3 89.7c2.6-12.9 5.2-22.4 7.9-33.6 2.5-10.6 4.2-20.5 7.4-31.9 1.8-6.3 5.7-15 12.2-15.3 14.1-0.7 27.9 1.5 41.9 2.2 14.3 0.7 28.5 1.3 42.8 2.2 13.5 0.9 27.1 2.2 40.6 3.1 14.7 0.9 29.4 1.4 44.1 2.2 14.4 0.8 28.8 1.7 43.2 2.6 12.1 0.8 24.1 1.9 36.2 2.6 11.3 0.7 22.7 1 34.1 1.6 2.7 0.2 5.4 0.4 8.1 0.5 4 0.2 8.7 2.7 8.6 6.5 0 1.3 0 2.6 0 3.8-0.1 12.4-0.2 22.3-0.1 35.6 0 2.6-0.4 9.7-4.5 10.3-8.2 1.1-17.9 1.2-26.9 1.7-30.4 1.9-60.8 3.8-91.2 5.7-28.2 1.8-56.5 3.6-84.7 5.2-21 1.2-41.9 2.2-62.9 3.5-13.4 0.8-26.8 1.6-40.2 2.6-8.4 0.6-17.9-4.8-16.6-11.4z" >
  <!--   <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    dur="2s"
    values="772;0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> -->
 </path> 
<text class="txt" x="179" y="65"  > В КОРЗИНУ </text> 
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Анимация из одной точки SVG**

Длина бордюра делится на пополам и с помощью изменения параметров атрибута `stroke-dasharray` реализуется анимация двух рамок на встречу друг другу

```
 <animate
       attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
       begin="svg1.mouseover"
       dur="2s"
       values="0 372.5 0 372.5;0 0 372.5 0"
       fill="freeze"
       restart="whenNotActive" />
```

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%
}
#trace_In {
fill:none;
stroke:#d3d3d3;
}
#trace_Out {
fill:none;
stroke:#d3d3d3;
}

#border_In {
fill:none;
stroke:#C532D4;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-dasharray:0,372.5,0,372.5;
}
#border_Out {
fill:none;
stroke:#C532D4;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-dasharray:772px;
stroke-dashoffset:772px;

}

.txt {
fill:#C532D4;
text-anchor:middle;
font-size:40px;
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 358 115" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >   
<defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow" width="120%" height="120%">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic"  stdDeviation="1" result="shadow" />
       
      <feOffset in="shadow" dx="2" dy="1" result="shadow" />
           
      <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="1.6 1.7 1.8 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 -0.04" result="shadow" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"  />
    </filter>
  </defs> 
 
   <!-- Серая внутренняя рамка, трасса анимации -->
 <path id="trace_In" d="m23.1 87.7c0.9-6.6 2.3-9.4 3.6-15.3 2.9-12.6 6-24.2 9.5-39.7 1-4.3 1.7-7.3 2.8-11.6 1.1-4.6 4.2-9 11.1-8.2 18.4 2.2 16.7 1.4 25.3 2 38.8 2.7 71.9 5.8 109.3 7.8 26.3 1.4 53.4 2.8 83 4.3 21.6 1.1 50.6 3 69.5 3.7 3.7 0.1 4.8-1.2 4.8 7.7-0.1 7.5 0 12.5 0.2 20.1 0.1 2.2 0.1 4.8 0.3 8 0.5 10.9-3 10.9-5.5 11.1-9.8 0.8-19.2 1.5-28.3 2.2-84.5 6.2-147 9.1-277 16.4-3.3 0.2-9.3-2.2-8.4-8.4z" />
 
 <!-- Розовая внутренняя рамка -->
 <path id="border_In" d="m23.1 87.7c0.9-6.6 2.3-9.4 3.6-15.3 2.9-12.6 6-24.2 9.5-39.7 1-4.3 1.7-7.3 2.8-11.6 1.1-4.6 4.2-9 11.1-8.2 18.4 2.2 16.7 1.4 25.3 2 38.8 2.7 71.9 5.8 109.3 7.8 26.3 1.4 53.4 2.8 83 4.3 21.6 1.1 50.6 3 69.5 3.7 3.7 0.1 4.8-1.2 4.8 7.7-0.1 7.5 0 12.5 0.2 20.1 0.1 2.2 0.1 4.8 0.3 8 0.5 10.9-3 10.9-5.5 11.1-9.8 0.8-19.2 1.5-28.3 2.2-84.5 6.2-147 9.1-277 16.4-3.3 0.2-9.3-2.2-8.4-8.4z" >
     <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    dur="2s"
    values="0 372.5 0 372.5;0 0 372.5 0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path>  
 <!-- Серая внешняя рамка, трасса анимации -->
  <path id="trace_Out" d="m18.3 89.7c2.6-12.9 5.2-22.4 7.9-33.6 2.5-10.6 4.2-20.5 7.4-31.9 1.8-6.3 5.7-15 12.2-15.3 14.1-0.7 27.9 1.5 41.9 2.2 14.3 0.7 28.5 1.3 42.8 2.2 13.5 0.9 27.1 2.2 40.6 3.1 14.7 0.9 29.4 1.4 44.1 2.2 14.4 0.8 28.8 1.7 43.2 2.6 12.1 0.8 24.1 1.9 36.2 2.6 11.3 0.7 22.7 1 34.1 1.6 2.7 0.2 5.4 0.4 8.1 0.5 4 0.2 8.7 2.7 8.6 6.5 0 1.3 0 2.6 0 3.8-0.1 12.4-0.2 22.3-0.1 35.6 0 2.6-0.4 9.7-4.5 10.3-8.2 1.1-17.9 1.2-26.9 1.7-30.4 1.9-60.8 3.8-91.2 5.7-28.2 1.8-56.5 3.6-84.7 5.2-21 1.2-41.9 2.2-62.9 3.5-13.4 0.8-26.8 1.6-40.2 2.6-8.4 0.6-17.9-4.8-16.6-11.4z" />
   <!-- Розовая внешняя рамка -->
  <path id="border_Out" d="m18.3 89.7c2.6-12.9 5.2-22.4 7.9-33.6 2.5-10.6 4.2-20.5 7.4-31.9 1.8-6.3 5.7-15 12.2-15.3 14.1-0.7 27.9 1.5 41.9 2.2 14.3 0.7 28.5 1.3 42.8 2.2 13.5 0.9 27.1 2.2 40.6 3.1 14.7 0.9 29.4 1.4 44.1 2.2 14.4 0.8 28.8 1.7 43.2 2.6 12.1 0.8 24.1 1.9 36.2 2.6 11.3 0.7 22.7 1 34.1 1.6 2.7 0.2 5.4 0.4 8.1 0.5 4 0.2 8.7 2.7 8.6 6.5 0 1.3 0 2.6 0 3.8-0.1 12.4-0.2 22.3-0.1 35.6 0 2.6-0.4 9.7-4.5 10.3-8.2 1.1-17.9 1.2-26.9 1.7-30.4 1.9-60.8 3.8-91.2 5.7-28.2 1.8-56.5 3.6-84.7 5.2-21 1.2-41.9 2.2-62.9 3.5-13.4 0.8-26.8 1.6-40.2 2.6-8.4 0.6-17.9-4.8-16.6-11.4z" >
     <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    dur="2s"
    values="772;0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path> 
<text class="txt" x="179" y="65"  > В КОРЗИНУ </text> 
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Ещё вариант анимации из одной точки SVG**

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#111;
}
#trace_In {
fill:none;
stroke:#828282;
}
#trace_Out {
fill:none;
stroke:#656565;
}

#border_In {
fill:none;
stroke:gold;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-dasharray:0,372.5,0,372.5;
stroke-dashoffset:372.5;
}
#border_Out {
fill:none;
stroke:gold;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-dasharray:0,386,0,386;
}

.txt {
fill:gold;
text-anchor:middle;
font-size:40px;
filter:url(#drop-shadow);
fill-opacity:0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 358 115" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >   
<defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow" width="120%" height="120%">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic"  stdDeviation="1" result="shadow" />
       
      <feOffset in="shadow" dx="2" dy="1" result="shadow" />
           
      <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="1.6 1.7 1.8 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 -0.04" result="shadow" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"  />
    </filter>
  </defs> 
 
   <!-- Серая внутренняя рамка, трасса анимации -->
 <path id="trace_In" d="m23.1 87.7c0.9-6.6 2.3-9.4 3.6-15.3 2.9-12.6 6-24.2 9.5-39.7 1-4.3 1.7-7.3 2.8-11.6 1.1-4.6 4.2-9 11.1-8.2 18.4 2.2 16.7 1.4 25.3 2 38.8 2.7 71.9 5.8 109.3 7.8 26.3 1.4 53.4 2.8 83 4.3 21.6 1.1 50.6 3 69.5 3.7 3.7 0.1 4.8-1.2 4.8 7.7-0.1 7.5 0 12.5 0.2 20.1 0.1 2.2 0.1 4.8 0.3 8 0.5 10.9-3 10.9-5.5 11.1-9.8 0.8-19.2 1.5-28.3 2.2-84.5 6.2-147 9.1-277 16.4-3.3 0.2-9.3-2.2-8.4-8.4z" />
 
 <!-- Розовая внутренняя рамка -->
 <path id="border_In" d="m23.1 87.7c0.9-6.6 2.3-9.4 3.6-15.3 2.9-12.6 6-24.2 9.5-39.7 1-4.3 1.7-7.3 2.8-11.6 1.1-4.6 4.2-9 11.1-8.2 18.4 2.2 16.7 1.4 25.3 2 38.8 2.7 71.9 5.8 109.3 7.8 26.3 1.4 53.4 2.8 83 4.3 21.6 1.1 50.6 3 69.5 3.7 3.7 0.1 4.8-1.2 4.8 7.7-0.1 7.5 0 12.5 0.2 20.1 0.1 2.2 0.1 4.8 0.3 8 0.5 10.9-3 10.9-5.5 11.1-9.8 0.8-19.2 1.5-28.3 2.2-84.5 6.2-147 9.1-277 16.4-3.3 0.2-9.3-2.2-8.4-8.4z" >
     <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    dur="2s"
    values="0 372.5 0 372.5;0 0 745 0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path>  
 <!-- Серая внешняя рамка, трасса анимации -->
  <path id="trace_Out" d="m18.3 89.7c2.6-12.9 5.2-22.4 7.9-33.6 2.5-10.6 4.2-20.5 7.4-31.9 1.8-6.3 5.7-15 12.2-15.3 14.1-0.7 27.9 1.5 41.9 2.2 14.3 0.7 28.5 1.3 42.8 2.2 13.5 0.9 27.1 2.2 40.6 3.1 14.7 0.9 29.4 1.4 44.1 2.2 14.4 0.8 28.8 1.7 43.2 2.6 12.1 0.8 24.1 1.9 36.2 2.6 11.3 0.7 22.7 1 34.1 1.6 2.7 0.2 5.4 0.4 8.1 0.5 4 0.2 8.7 2.7 8.6 6.5 0 1.3 0 2.6 0 3.8-0.1 12.4-0.2 22.3-0.1 35.6 0 2.6-0.4 9.7-4.5 10.3-8.2 1.1-17.9 1.2-26.9 1.7-30.4 1.9-60.8 3.8-91.2 5.7-28.2 1.8-56.5 3.6-84.7 5.2-21 1.2-41.9 2.2-62.9 3.5-13.4 0.8-26.8 1.6-40.2 2.6-8.4 0.6-17.9-4.8-16.6-11.4z" />
   <!-- Розовая внешняя рамка -->
  <path id="border_Out" d="m18.3 89.7c2.6-12.9 5.2-22.4 7.9-33.6 2.5-10.6 4.2-20.5 7.4-31.9 1.8-6.3 5.7-15 12.2-15.3 14.1-0.7 27.9 1.5 41.9 2.2 14.3 0.7 28.5 1.3 42.8 2.2 13.5 0.9 27.1 2.2 40.6 3.1 14.7 0.9 29.4 1.4 44.1 2.2 14.4 0.8 28.8 1.7 43.2 2.6 12.1 0.8 24.1 1.9 36.2 2.6 11.3 0.7 22.7 1 34.1 1.6 2.7 0.2 5.4 0.4 8.1 0.5 4 0.2 8.7 2.7 8.6 6.5 0 1.3 0 2.6 0 3.8-0.1 12.4-0.2 22.3-0.1 35.6 0 2.6-0.4 9.7-4.5 10.3-8.2 1.1-17.9 1.2-26.9 1.7-30.4 1.9-60.8 3.8-91.2 5.7-28.2 1.8-56.5 3.6-84.7 5.2-21 1.2-41.9 2.2-62.9 3.5-13.4 0.8-26.8 1.6-40.2 2.6-8.4 0.6-17.9-4.8-16.6-11.4z" >
     <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    dur="2s"
    values="0 386 0 386;0 0 772 0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path> 
<text class="txt" x="179" y="67"  > В КОРЗИНУ
 <animate attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="2s" values="0.2;1" begin="svg1.mouseover"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
 </text> 
</svg>  
</div>
```